# Problema al intentar recuperar un backup de GitLab para Docker

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab

Debido a problemas de mantenimiento he tenido que restaurar el equipo de fábrica. Antes de ello realicé una copia de seguridad del contenedor que tenía con GitLab mediante los siguientes pasos:

```
docker commit -p  78727078a04b  gitlab_backup

docker save -o /container_backup.tar gitlab_backup
```

Y he guardado el archivo .tar.

Bien, una vez he dejado el ordenador como nuevo. Uno de los cambios más notables que tengo es que me ha cambiado la ip estática interna que tenía. Si antes era 192.168.0.177 ahora es la 192.168.0.198.

Tras instalar docker de nuevo, he comenzado a importar la copia con los siguientes pasos:

```
docker load -i /container_backup.tar
```

Y aquí es donde dudo si estoy creando un contenedor correctamente a partir de esta imagen. Esto es lo que realizo:

```
docker run --detach 
--hostname localhost 
--publish 443:443 --publish 7842:80 --publish 2098:22 
--name gitlab --restart always gitlab_backup:latest
```

El contenedor se crea y corre, pero a la hora de acceder con el navegador me dice que esta página no funciona. Si creo un contenedor a partir de la imagen oficial de GitLab, funciona bien, pero con esta no consigo recuperar lo que tenía, y no se por donde tirar ahora.

Gracias de antemano.